# How can I restrict myself to playing starcraft 2 between the hours of 10pm and 1am?

Tags: windows-7, starcraft2

I have a lot of work to do and my life is falling apart because of this incredibly fun game.  I'm on the verge of throwing my copy into the lake I live on to avoid fully transforming into a twelve year old, but I don't want to stop playing altogether.  I'd rather restrict myself to only playing in the evenings, but I don't have the discipline to do that.  Is there any software or native Windows 7 utilities I can use to restrict myself to only playing starcraft 2 between 10pm and 1am?

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered restricting yourself with the built-in parental controls? [Windows 7 Parental Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/features/parental-controls.aspx) allow you to specify which games are allowed during which hours. I feel a bit silly suggesting parental controls to an adult, but that may do the trick.

You could set up a "get stuff done" user account and a "play time" user account. Remove all links to games from the "get stuff done" account, and then use parental controls or `net user` to restrict your "play" account to only be able to log in [during certain hours](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_user.mspx?mfr=true). You could additionally use the parental controls to prevent the "get stuff done" account from playing any games at all, and you can disable whatever other programs you want that might be a distraction, like IM clients, other games, twitter apps, etc.

[image: User Controls - Disable Games]

[image: Logon time restrictions]

Now, does somebody have a way for me to stop distracting myself on SU? ;)

Comment: And, of course, give you wife the password for the admin/parental controls so you can't change the settings without her cooperation.

Comment: You can have a wife _and_ play StarCraft? Unpossible! Not enough time!

Answer (score 5):

by sheer will. either that or deinstall <insert_game_name>.

nothing else will help. if you do not have the will, you will bypass your own "restrictions" anyway if you do not have the will. if you realize that you do not have the will, deinstall the game. use an os not capable of playing the game.

if you have the will, just set the time of your mobile phone to ring at a certain time and then shutdown the machine.

Comment: +1. There's no software solution for lack of self-discipline. Any software you set up to block you is just as easily uninstalled.

Answer (score 3):

All that applications won't work until you really wish to stop playing. And if you wish, you don't need them.
Best way to stop playing - to find more interesting things. Like friends in RL, girl/boy-friend. Start some project (e.g create map). Start learning something.

PS: i know that sc2 is really fun game, and i playing it myself like 20 hours per week :)